# How to make the most of your companions?

Tags: diablo-iii, ps4

How can I make the most out of my companions in Diablo 3 ROS? I realize they won't be doing as much damage as I do, but I've chosen their perks, I keep their weapons and gear updated as best I can, but they still feel useless to me, and even at level 55, they're not helping me much in terms of DPS.

Comment: The companions are helpful more for healing and crowd control more than for dps.

Comment: It also depends what class you are. Some companions work better with certain classes. i.e. My Wizard really benefits from the Templar because of his tankiness and healing. I don't count on my companion for any DPS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many ways to benefit from your followers. Even though they don't deal much damage, they can offer you some good support utility.

### 1 - The Enchanteress

**Skills**

- **Charm**, **Disorient** and **Mass Control** allow you to benefit from effect versus ennemies under control imparing effect (like [**Bane of the Trapped**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bane-of-the-trapped)).
- **Missile Ward** and **Powered Armor** both offer some welcome and free toughness.
- You can get more damage for free with **Erosion** and **Focused Minds**.

**Items**

- [**Maximus**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/maximus) will allow you to get a Sumonned Demon.
- [**The Tormentor**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-tormentor) has a chance to charm ennemies on hit.
- [**The Grand Vizier**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-grand-vizier-3jdOKy) : in its legacy version could roll with high (up to +50%) magic find and gold find. So a nice bonus for you.

### 2 - The Scoundrel

**Skills**

- **Crippling Shot**, **Dirty Fighting** and **Powered Shot** offer some Crowd Control, once again helping to trigger items like [**Bane of the Trapped**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bane-of-the-trapped).
- **Hysteria** or **Anatomy** will boost your damage for free.

**Items**

There is only one item I'd recommand to get on Lyndon and it is : [**Buriza-Do Kyanon**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/burizado-kyanon). This items synergizes very well with his skill **Multishot**. Each arrow he shoots has up to 10% chance (15% if you have a legacy version of Buriza) to freeze the target on hit aswell as piercing thus hitting and freezing foes behind too. Thanks to multishot Lyndon shoots 3 arrow at a time so you can imagine the potential for this combo. You can even add (if you find it) a legacy version of [**The Star of Azkaranth**](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-star-of-azkaranth-3rGE4L) which would boost his chance to freeze on hit to 20%. Thats a huge Crowd Control boost.

### 3 - The Templar

My favourite because it offers my class (Demon Hunter) some welcome sustainability and is aswell a permanent Crowd Control source if used correctly.

**Skills**

- **Heal**, **Loyalty** and **Inspire** bring some welcome sustain for life and ressource (especially in Greater Rifts)
- **Charge** offers some welcome Crowd Control and will make the Templar go in melee range and take the aggro of the mobs which can be very helpful.

But for me the Templar shines with a special combo :

**Intimidate** : This skill allows you to have almost permanently slowed ennemies arround the Templar. If used with [**Bul-Kathoss' Wedding Band**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bulkathoss-wedding-band) (a ring that drains life from, and so inflict damage to, all enemies arround you) in duo with [**Thunderfury**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/thunderfury-blessed-blade-of-the-windseeker) (the lightning bolt has a huge range and allows the Templar to aggro mob from very far and still slow them by 80% for 3 second). Using this method you can benefit from items like [**Bane of the Trapped**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bane-of-the-trapped) or skills like [**Cull the weak**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/demon-hunter/passive/cull-the-weak) permanently without having to think about how to slow your foes.

### 4 - In general

You can get the following items on any follower :

- [**The Ess of Johan**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-ess-of-johan) will occasionally (often enough for you to notice) pull all enemies toward the target of your follower. This can be helpful to group up mobs in the same place and use your AOE more effectively.
- [**Overwhelming Desire**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/overwhelming-desire-1I0LYo) has a chance to Charm ennemies on hit and they also suffer from 35% more damage. It doesn't work on Boss though usefull enough on elites for you to use it.

**Last but not least** : the most used trick with followers is to have both you and the follower use [**Unity**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/unity) and put a Follower items that makes him invulnerable ([**The Focus**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/smoking-thurible), [**The Relic**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/enchanting-favor) or [**The Token**](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/skeleton-key)). The actual effect of those items are *Your follower doesn't take damage anymore*. This implies that when the follower gets hit he takes 0 damage so the Unity's effect doesnt affect you. However when you take damage, 50% of those damage are redirected to the follower who doesn't take any. That's a net free **50% damage reduction**.

Comment: Great write up, but to make this answer truly amazing would be to take out the legacy items and put in the new legendaries.

Comment: This is really helpful, but ChaseC is right, I don't think I've ever found any of those items (save for a low-level Thunderfury on my HC Crusader). But definitely a good guide!

Comment: Well I guess you're right for the Star of Azkaranth which mlight be very hard to find. However the other 2 (Grand Vizier and Buriza) still stands. The buriza still rolls with up to 10% freeze on hit chance (not 15% but still) and the Grand Vizier can still roll high GF. All the other item mentionned are obtainable at present through looting/gambling at Kadala :D

Answer (score 7):

To "get the most" out of your Follower (a bit different than a companion which is the term for a Demon Hunter's friendly animals that are enabled by a skill or Marauder's set) you have to reconsider what their usefulness is.

Many players will tell you, trying to maximize a Follower's DPS is all in vain, as their DPS is only a pittance of your main character's ultimate capabilities. In fact, by the time you are level 70 and start working on 'min-max'ing a build, your Follower will only do a fraction of a percent of damage that you can, even with the absolute best items.

Instead, you have to focus on support abilities and legendary item combinations that can turn the tides.

For most players, the most useful Follower, is one who sports a Unity ring with a Token that has the legendary ability of "Your Follower cannot die". Couple this with a Unity ring on your own character and that is the most usefulness you can get out of a Follower as they will effectively mitigate 50% of your taken damage.

There's other tricks you can do with Followers also, but most fall short of being efficient.

Comment: Also, item combinations like wyrdward and the thunderfury (wieldable only by Kormac) can help stunning enemies frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Get 2 unitys(share 50 % dmg with whoever else has this ring, including your follower) one for yourself and one for your follower. Then get the trinket on the follower ( whichever you get first ) that they cant't die. Proceed to enjoy 50 % permanent DmG reduction.